# Input type file not opens in IOS Safari in navigation.getCurrentLocations success callback

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function and in sucess callback i call click method on `<input type="file" capture="camera" />` to force to open phone camera to take a photo, but file dialog is not opening. Nothing happening. Maybe someone knows why? On Android browser all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In ios you cant call click on Video and upload files, The user has to click on them to start it.

When we clicked the button, the registered handler function was executed, and the browser kept track of the fact that it was the user who initiated that button click event, not some piece of code. Outside of such user-initiated events, file dialogs cannot be opened programmatically.

Find more info here:
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/programmatically-opening-a-file-dialog-with-javascript